Snowsql error "Unexpected keyword file"001003 (42000): syntax error line 1 at position 4 unexpected 'file'."
I am trying to load the data into a internal stage using the snowsql put file command.
But it through an error.
001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 4 unexpected 'file'.
Command: put file ://C:\Practice\scorecard.csv @test;
please tell me why am i getting this error
I tried the following commands, but still it throughs the same error.
put file ://C:\Practice\scorecard.csv @test;
PUT FILE ://C:\Practice\scorecard.csv @test;

I am not SQL literate, but for anyone to answer your question, I believe you will need to share the file in the *.csv file being processed.  That way people desiring to help can see what is on line 4 to provide help.

@RossYoungblood did you not see my answer below?

@NickW It would seem Stackoverflow is turning into a replacement for reading quite simply documentation. Only that, but these folk seem to refuse to accept answers. Fire and forget questions....

Because you have a space between "file" and the ":"
